# android:java.net.sockettimeout exception

Tags: java, android, .net, web-services, android-ksoap2

Actually I am developing an android app...i need to fetch more than 100 rows from .net webservice..(using ksoap2)..but when i call the webservice i am getting socket timeout..exception..instead of fetching 100 rows i tried fetchin 30 rows..which worked fine..so i am unable to recognize the problem whether the problem is with .net webservice or in my android.
I just want to know is there any alternative way to fetch large amount of data in meantime.

I also added permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Code:

```
 package school.demo;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
 import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
 import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
 import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.GridView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class Code extends Activity {

Button b1;
TextView t1;
String s = "11-10-2012";
int c = 0, j = 0;
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<String, String> map;
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://TestClass/";
private static final String URL = "http://***.**.**.**/TestClass/Service1.asmx";
private static final String HelloWorld_SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://TestClass/getdata";
private static final String METHOD_NAME2 = "getdata";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.accounts);
    GridView g1 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME2);
    request.addProperty("Uname", s);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    httpTransport.setTimeout(MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    try {
        httpTransport.call(HelloWorld_SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

        SoapObject res = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
        SoapObject root = (SoapObject) res.getProperty(0);
        SoapObject s_deals = (SoapObject) root.getProperty("Table1");
        String s = s_deals.toString();
        httpTransport.requestDump="TRUE";
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s,
        //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        for (int i = 1; i < root.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            Object o = root.getProperty(i);
            SoapObject main = (SoapObject) o;
            String f1 = main.getProperty(1).toString();
            String f2 = main.getProperty(2).toString();
            String f3 = main.getProperty(3).toString();
            String f4 = main.getProperty(4).toString();
            String f5 = main.getProperty(5).toString();
            //String f6 = main.getProperty(6).toString();
            al.add(f1);
            al.add(f2);
            al.add(f3);

        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter a1 = new ArrayAdapter(Code.this, R.layout.blows,
                R.id.textView1, al);
        g1.setAdapter(a1);
        g1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + arg2,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        }
     }
```

Comment: any warning error in logcat then share it here

Comment: Erm, don't set the timeout? You're explicitly setting it (to something that doesn't *sound* like a timeout value), then asking why it times out after some ... time?

Comment: Error Log..Timed out while retrieving the attached javadoc for Activity {key=Landroid/app/Activity;} [in Activity.class [in android.app [in E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platforms\android-10\android.jar]]]

Comment: i removed the timeout and checked it..still facing the same problem....

Comment: logcat errors:                                                                              GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 54% free 2544K/5511K, external 410K/517K, paused 53ms

01-03 10:53:13.143: D/dalvikvm(141): GC_EXPLICIT freed 118K, 50% free 2988K/5895K, external 1241K/1559K, paused 102ms
 2537K/5511K, external 410K/517K, paused 65ms

01-03 10:53:23.213: D/dalvikvm(227): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 54% free 2597K/5639K, external 410K/517K, paused 137ms
01-03 10:53:25.908: D/SntpClient(61): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: @Brain Roach-i removed the time out parameter and checked it...

Comment: try calling the webservice outside the UI thread....i.e using an intentservice or AsyncTask

Comment: dont use it in on create . try to use in AsyncTask. before that check whether internet is there or not ... and Use HTTPRESPONSE correctly to check socket time out. if our internet is very slow we will get it this issue.

Comment: please provide any sample code for AsyncTask..pls..there is no problem in internet connection..it's working fine..